# iText: Chapters placed into dual column format

Tags: java, itext

I am writing a program in Java using iText 5. A big part of the program involves printing things out to PDF, and a big part of that is a human readable dictionary.

Given a chapter that contains phrases of all the words in my dictionary, is there any way to hand this to iText and have it align this in 2 column per page format? Essentially, I'm looking for pages that read left half top to left half bottom->right half top to right half bottom->next page. Anyone familiar with oldschool paper style dictionaries will be familiar with what I'm talking about here, and that's the look that I'm going for.

Sorry that I don't have any example code to go off of here, but I'm kind of stymied, as I haven't been able to find anything that does what I want.

Comment: This is possible with iText 5 using `ColumnText`, but it's some work. It's much easier with iText 7. Take a look at the screen shots in Chapter 2 of the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) tutorial and look for where it uses `ColumnDocumentRenderer`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice there! I did see that it's a lot easier to do with iText 7, but that unfortunately costs money, and I'm doing an open source project with incompatible licenses.

Comment: Your choice of license is your own. Choose the AGPL and you can build on the iText 7 platform (or on iText 5). If you choose iText 7, we will even promote your product and help you make money with it. I really don't understand your comment. Both iText 5 and iText 7 are licensed under the AGPL, so if you're doing an open source project using a license that is incompatible with iText 7, it will also be incompatible with iText 5 (which is the version you are using according to your question).

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that iText 7 could be used with AGPL! I think I just saw that the *addons* required a professional license and confused it there. Thanks again for pointing this and the proper document out to me!

Comment: Some add-ons will be offered as closed source product only; some as AGPL / commercial under a dual license.  We're now working on a platform to start offering third party add-ons too. A developer has built a system to parse invoices, but he doesn't have any sales people. We've asked him to port his iText 5 to an iText 7 add-on. Once he's finished, we'll start offering his add-on to our customers. We'll share the revenue with the developer. This is currently only an experiment, but if it works for all parties, we hope we can build a good business for everyone.